# Which command to know the time when a server has booted up? (boot time history)

Tags: linux

I would like to know the time when a linux box has booted up last year. Is there any way to ask the computer at which time it has been booted up ?

thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `uptime` or `last -x`.

Comment: Thanks but this gives the actual boot time, what I'm looking for is a list of boot times.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned `last -x`. Depending on your log rotation policy you might need to provide another `wtmp` file e. g. `last -x -f /var/log/wtmp.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Last should give you the boot times, looking for the reboot or boot usernames.  If need be you may need to find and use the flag that lets you load the older last logs

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `ps aux | grep init` gives you detailed enough information? After a long(ish) uptime it shows you the date the init process was started.

If that's not accurate enough, see **/proc/stat** and the **btime** value there. It's the Unix time in seconds when the system was last booted up. To parse it, use your favourite date manipulating tool, for example Perl Date::Manip module:

`grep btime /proc/stat | cut -d ' ' -f2 | perl -MDate::Manip -lane 'printf "%s\n", UnixDate(ParseDateString("epoch $_"), "%c");'`

In my test server that returns

`Mon Jul 19 15:45:12 2010`

Which is the last the the server was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, there's the `uprecords` utility that records all your `uptime` history. You have to install it first to start recording your uptimes though (i.e. it won't show your past uptimes).